What Are the Key Differences Between Alluxio SDK Cache and File Merger Cache in Presto's Hive Connector?
I’m currently using a Hive connector with Presto, which supports two cache services: 1. Alluxio and 2. File Merger Cache. I want to cache remote data into local storage.
While there’s documentation available for the Alluxio SDK cache, I couldn’t find any detailed information on the File Merger Cache.
I tried using the FILE_MERGE caching option, but I’d like to understand the key differences between Alluxio SDK cache and File Merger Cache, especially since both store the cache locally.
Can anyone provide more details or point me to documentation on the File Merger Cache?
